# Deserializing json throwing 'Additional text encountered' error

Tags: c#, .net, json

So I am trying to deserialize some data into a collection.
I am getting an issue when I try to deserialize the contents of a file that contains the json.

This is how I store the data.

```
WebItem = new WebsiteItemViewModel
                    {
                        Title = "Twitter Item",
                        Description = "Here is a long description that might be crossing the bounds but thats fine.",
                        Image = "../resources/twitter.png"
                    };

                    string resultJson2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(WebItem);
                    File.AppendAllText("Testfile", resultJson2);
```

And this is how I try to deserialzie the data :

```
private void OnLoadData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string data = File.ReadAllText("Testfile");
            var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebsiteItemViewModel>(data);
        }
```

But when I click to deserialize it throws that error

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered
>   after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 1, position
>   154.'

And this is what the json data looks like.

> {"Title":"Facebook Item","Description":"Here is a long description
>   that might be crossing the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/Facebook.png"}{"Title":"Facebook
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/Facebook.png"}{"Title":"Twitter
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/twitter.png"}{"Title":"Facebook
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/Facebook.png"}{"Title":"Twitter
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/twitter.png"}{"Title":"Twitter
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/twitter.png"}{"Title":"Facebook
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/Facebook.png"}{"Title":"Facebook
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/Facebook.png"}{"Title":"Twitter
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/twitter.png"}{"Title":"Facebook
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/Facebook.png"}{"Title":"Twitter
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/twitter.png"}{"Title":"Twitter
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/twitter.png"}{"Title":"Facebook
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/Facebook.png"}{"Title":"Facebook
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/Facebook.png"}{"Title":"Facebook
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats
>   fine.","Image":"../resources/Facebook.png"}{"Title":"Twitter
>   Item","Description":"Here is a long description that might be crossing
>   the bounds but thats fine.","Image":"../resources/twitter.png"}

**Model**

```
[Serializable]
public class ClassName...

[JsonProperty("Title")]
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty("Description")]
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set
            {
                _description = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty("Image")]
        public string Image
        {
            get { return _image; }
            set
            {
                _image = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Image");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your json data isn't valid

Comment: The content of the file doesn't seem to be a valid json. It seems because of using `File.AppendAllText` you are just putting some json objects after each other in the file.

Comment: Oh, how do I append one object at a time to make id valid?

Comment: @MarkDenom Did you want to read the json data be an array?

Comment: In fact you need to store a json array in the file.

Comment: I want to store the data in a file and then I want to read it as a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would deserializeObject Json data to be `List<WebsiteItemViewModel>` collection object by a method.

```
private List<WebsiteItemViewModel> readData()
{
    string data = File.ReadAllText("Testfile");
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WebsiteItemViewModel>>(data) ?? new List<WebsiteItemViewModel>();
}
```

then you can append your `WebsiteItemViewModel` type  `WebItem` new object in the collection the use `WriteAllText` to overwrite the file to make sure the JSON data is the newest.

```
var list = readData();

WebsiteItemViewModel WebItem = new WebsiteItemViewModel
{
    Title = "Twitter Item",
    Description = "Here is a long description that might be crossing the bounds but thats fine.",
    Image = "../resources/twitter.png"
};

list.Add(WebItem);
string resultJson2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
File.WriteAllText("Testfile", resultJson2);
```

**NOTE**

use `WriteAllText` instead of `AppendAllText` because `AppendAllText` will append the JSON data on the end.

`WriteAllText` will overwrite the file to keep your JSON be a valid array string.

Comment: Ahh that makes alot of sense, new to json.net this was a good answer

Comment: @MarkDenom No problem glad to help:)

Comment: What if the file is empty to begin with? Then it will throw a null exception

Comment: sorry I miss it use `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WebsiteItemViewModel>>(data) ?? new List<WebsiteItemViewModel>();`  in the return method. to make sure the array would not be `null`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not serialized all objects as an array of objects, you are missing the opening and ending braces as far as I can see in your json file. In other words you have not constructed a proper json file.